# running Hadoop with HBase: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to make a mapreduce program on Hadoop using HBase. I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 with HBase 0.98.10.1.

The program can be compiled successfully and being made into a jar file. But, when I try to run the jar using "hadoop jar" the program shows error says:

> "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String".

Here is the line of code I used to initiate the HTable.

```
HBaseConfiguration config = new HBaseConfiguration();
HTable table = new HTable(config, "Test");
```

What should I change to overcome this error?

Comment: I've somehow solved this error by just re-installing both Hadoop 2.5.1 and HBase 0.98.10 (I still have no idea why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've somehow solved this error by just re-installing both Hadoop 2.5.1 and HBase 0.98.10